# Python - Removing parenthesis around bit-wise shift operators giving different results during addition

Tags: python, bitwise-operators, bit-shift, operator-precedence, parentheses

I was coding for multiplication using Karatsuba Algorithm and it required some bit shifting. Keeping it short, I needed to convert this mathematical expression to programming statement:

[image: mathematical formula for karatsuba]

Without any parenthesis and confirming that **addition (+) has precedence over bit-wise shift operators (<<)**, I wrote this statement:

```
product = (high_part<<m)<<m + middle_part<<m + low_part
```

For `high_part, middle_part, low_part = 0, 0, 1`, this gives `product = 0`. The correct answer, if you calculate, is **2**.

I get different answers with different order of the variables in the statement. For example, `high_part, middle_part, low_part = 0, 0, 1` and

```
product = middle_part<<m + low_part + (high_part<<m)<<m
```

gives `product = 4`.

Well, when I put parenthesis around the three addends, I get the correct answer (`product = 2`):

```
product = ((high_part<<m)<<m) + (middle_part<<m) + (low_part)
```

***Is this a precedence issue or am I missing something weird here?***

Comment: `+` has higher precedence than `<<` therefore the first variant is equivalent to `product = (high_part<<m)<<(m + middle_part)<<(m + low_part)`.

Comment: Its got to do with order of precedence of operations.
http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~valerie/courses/fall10/155/resources/op_precedence.html

Bitshift operators have lower precedence over arithmetic operators.

Comment: you didn't mentioned the value of m for which you are getting the above output

Comment: @KousikMitra `m = 1`.

Comment: @MichaelButscher (and fzn), as I had mentioned in the question, I had already inquired about the precedence and still I don't know how could I still evaluate it wrongly. Thanks, for clearing up the confusion by posting the equivalent statement. My bad!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look carefully at the [Python documentation on operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence), you will see that `+` apply before `<<` (the same way `*` apply before `+`).

Comment: I had already inquired about the precedence but still got the evaluation wrong somehow. Accepting the answer! :)